# How to filter windows messages from a managed DLL

Tags: windows, user-interface, winapi

How can I get UI framework independent (WinForms, WPF, other frameworks) way to filter windows messages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows messages *are* framework dependent.
WPF actually tries to hide this away from you but it depends on the old win32 message loop still for much of it's behaviour. WinForms is just a paper thin (and badly incomplete) wrapper on win32 too.

The techniques for [sharing them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348549.aspx) are probably useful in terms of writing a common filter function and hooking that up to all the different frameworks.

Note that, as the framework distances itself further from the win32 model the set of messages that are meaningful to intercept becomes fewer and fewer.